# Add user to entry user field [RSVP to Event]

Tags: entries, users, field

I'm trying to add an RSVP button for users to register their attendance at my events. Once they click the button, I would like them to be added to a field called `eventAttendees` on the event entry.

My guess is this could be done as a form submission, and this is as far as I've gotten before getting a bit lost. I'm not sure how to pass the user ID to the entry.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ hiddenInput('entryId', event.id) }}
  {{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}
  <input type="hidden" name="fields[eventAttendees][]">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RSVP</button>
</form>
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a form that would do both RSVP and cancel RSVP, you could do the following:

```twig
{% set currentUserId = currentUser.id %}

{% set currentAttendees = event.eventAttendees.ids() %}

{# Is the current user attending? #}
{% set attending = currentUserId in currentAttendees %}

{# If the current user is attending, we remove its ID from the attendees (cancel action) #}
{# If the current user is not attending, we add its ID to the attendees (rsvp action) #}
{% set attendees = attending ? currentAttendees | filter(v => v != currentUserId) : currentAttendees | merge([currentUserId]) %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('entryId', event.id) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[eventAttendees][]">
    {% for attendee in attendees %}
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[eventAttendees][]" value="{{ attendee }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ attending ? 'Cancel RSVP' : 'RSVP' }}</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. If you have some time to help more, I have two issues. First is if the user is logged out, I get `Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.`

Second, unfortunately the 'Cancel RSVP' doesn't actually remove the user from the entry.

Very much appreciate any further help you can give.

Comment: @tommysvr This would only work for actual users and would require them to be registered and logged in otherwise Craft/you wouldn't know who is trying to RSVP for an event. In regard to cancelation, I just tried and (with a registerer, logged in user) it seems to work fine. Are you having issues with a logged in user?

Comment: Ah. Of course - I will add a check for logged in.

Yeah, logged in I am able to RSVP ok but when that changes to Cancel, nothing happens after clicking the button.

This my full event query: https://gist.github.com/tommysvr/1d512eaf8528daec9c097a7622dfd8ac

Comment: @tommysvr Ooops... Just spotted the error and I have edited the code above (new line after `hiddenInput`). It should work fine now.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much - seriously appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```twig
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('entryId', event.id) }}
    {% for user in event.eventAttendees %}
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[eventAttendees][]" value="{{ user.id }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[eventAttendees][]" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RSVP</button>
</form>
```

The `for` loop in there is to ensure that you do not remove any value (users) that have already RSVP. This is similar to [Uploading Files from Front-End Entry Forms](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Oli, that did the job!

Comment: I wonder if it would be too cheeky to now get a cancel RSVP version :D

I suppose that would have to check if the user.id exists in the field and then show a different form to do the opposite...